# NSFetchedResultsController, grouped UITableView, HeaderInSection and NSSortDescriptor

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios5

I have a NSFetchRequest with NSSortDesctriptors attached to a NSFetchedResultController providing data (see table example) for a UITableView which is in grouped mode and displays section headers.

I have some problems getting my head around proper sorting to display sections.

**Data:**

```
+---+----------+------------+----------+
|id | subTitle | groupTitle | distance |
+---+----------+------------+----------+
|1  | A        | T1         | 1.1      |
+---+----------+------------+----------+
|2  | B        | T1         | 1.2      |
+---+----------+------------+----------+
|3  | C        | T1         | 3.0      |
+---+----------+------------+----------+
|4  | D        | T2         | 1.3      |
+---+----------+------------+----------+
|5  | E        | T2         | 1.4      |
+---+----------+------------+----------+
|6  | F        | T3         | 1.5      |
+---+----------+------------+----------+
```

**What I have:**

`NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"groupTitle" ascending:YES];`

```
--T1
------A
------B
------C
--T2
------D
------E
--T3
------F
```

**What I want: (sort by distance but group by groupTitle for each following items in same group)**

`NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"distance" ascending:YES];`

```
--T1
------A
------B
--T2
------D
------E
--T3
------F
--T1
------C
```

**How could I achieve this behavior?** probably with the viewForHeaderInSection method?
What if the section to be grouped is not in the first hierarchy of the `[self.fetchedResultsController sections]`?

```
//custom header
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    SomeObject *cellEntity = (SomeObject *)[[sectionInfo objects] objectAtIndex:0];
    //cellEntity.groupTitle is the title 
    return aView;
}
```

Comment: you can add a core data entity attribute programmaticly wich represents the sorting that you actually need, but this can't be a solution for larger data sets.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting up your NSFetchedResultsController this way?  This should sort first by the group title and then by the distance.  Then it should break it by the group.

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"MyEntity"];
NSSortDescriptor *groupTitleSort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"groupTitle" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *distanceSort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:distance ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:groupTitleSort, distanceSort, nil];
request.sortDescriptor = sortArray;
NSFetchedResultController *fetchedResults = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:myManagedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"groupTitle" cacheName:@"MyCache"];

...Finish performing fetch...
```

Comment: this is not what i need, it should be sorted by distance in first place but grouped by groupTitle:


NSArray *sortArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:distanceSort, groupTitleSort, nil];


this is what i need, but this breaks the grouping because the first section in the fetchedResultController is the distance then.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood what you meant.  I don't think the NSFetchRequest will do what you need.  Just sort your objects by distance and then groupTitle.  Then use the array as your data source instead of NSFetchRequest.  The play the part of the NSFetchRequest by pre-counting sections (changes in groupTitle) and the number of rows between changes.  Use this to return in the DataSource delegate.